# Why does a LEFT JOIN break my MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
SELECT value AS $point_fld, COUNT(value) as cnt
FROM ?_data d LEFT JOIN
     ?_user u
     ON d.`table` = 'user' AND d.`id` = u.user_id
WHERE `key` = ? AND `value`<>'' AND `value`<>'Blank' AND
      u.added BETWEEN ? AND ?

/* ----- I added this bit */
LEFT JOIN ?_invoice_payment p
ON d.'id' = p.user_id
SUM(p.amount) as moneysum
/* End ---- */
GROUP BY $point_fld
```

I am trying to edit this query to add in a sum value for payments based on which users are returned in the first part. The commented text is what I added. It is working just as intended but when I add in my part to get the values it breaks it.

Any suggestions would be amazing thanks. I'm pretty new to joins and stuff in SQL.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is a keyword used only in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: so does that mean I would have to do it in a completely separate query?  or is there a way to do what i want from within this same query?

Comment: I've never seen that `?_xxx` notation before, are you trying to parameterize table names? Where is that permitted?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT value AS $point_fld, 
       COUNT(value) as cnt, 
       SUM(p.amount) as moneysum
FROM ?_data d 
INNER JOIN ?_user u ON d.`table` = 'user' AND d.`id` = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN ?_invoice_payment p ON d.'id' = p.user_id
WHERE `key` = ? AND `value`<>'' AND `value`<>'Blank' AND
      u.added BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY value
```

Comment: @elrobbo6: when asking a question and responding to an answer, please **always** explain what difficulty you are having. That is twice now that you have received an error or experienced some other problem, and then not told us what the issue is. Here, Michael has had to elicit further information from you, which makes both helping and getting an answer a slower process. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

OK this is what finally worked.  Thanks for the help!

SELECT value AS $point_fld, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT u.user_id) as cnt, 
       SUM(p.amount) as moneysum
FROM ?_data d 
LEFT JOIN ?_user u ON d.`table` = 'user' AND d.`id` = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN ?_invoice_payment p ON d.`id` = p.user_id
WHERE `key` = ? AND `value`<>'' AND `value`<>'Blank' AND 
      u.added BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY value